# problem in making custom root certificate store for SSL using QT?

Tags: qtwebkit, qtnetwork

I am developing my custom browser in Qt using QWebView and
I am trying to make my own root cert store of trusted certificates which are taken from mozilla project.

I have used QSslSocket::setDefaultCaCertificates() to override the default certificates.
But I am not able to load  https://www.gmail.com , where as in mozilla it works.

I have set all required root certs for gmail to my store.

can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you can't connect is because the SSL certificate (with serial `2F:DF:BC:F6:AE:91:52:6D:0F:9A:A3:DF:40:34:3E:9A`) presented to you when you connect to www.gmail.com is issued for a different domain - www.google.com. This has nothing to do with root CA certificate store because no root CA certificate is needed to compare cert's Subject CN field with the host you are trying to connect to. You can ignore this and other SSL errors by calling
[`void QNetworkReply::ignoreSslErrors () [virtual slot]`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qnetworkreply.html#ignoreSslErrors)
To avoid this error you can connect directly to https://mail.google.com which is the domain you are being redirected to when you try to connect to https://www.gmail.com

Below is a working example which will show you the exact SSL errors and QNAM level errors. Either line B1 or line B2 must be active at the same time. You can comment line A if you want to see what happens with the default (system) root CA certificate store. There are two certs used by this code; CA's cert with serial `30:00:00:02` should be placed in a file called `ThawteSGCCA.crt` and CA's cert with serial `70:BA:E4:1D:10:D9:29:34:B6:38:CA:7B:03:CC:BA:BF` should be placed in a file called `BuiltinObjectToken-VerisignClass3PublicPrimaryCertificationAuthority.crt`.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QList>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QtNetwork/QSslConfiguration>
#include <QtNetwork/QSslSocket>
#include <QtNetwork/QSslError>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebFrame>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebPage>



class Handler : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:

    void slotLoadFinished(bool ok) {
        if (ok) {
            qDebug() << "Page size: " << static_cast<QWebPage*>(sender())->mainFrame()->toHtml().size();
        }
    }

    void slotFinished(QNetworkReply * reply) {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            qDebug() << "connected to " << reply->url();
            qDebug() << "HTTP status: " << reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();

        } else {
            qDebug() << "error while connecting to " << reply->url();
            qDebug() << "error code: " << reply->error();
            qDebug() << "error string: " << reply->errorString();
        }
    }

    void slotSslErrors(QNetworkReply * reply, QList<QSslError> const & errors) {
        qDebug() << "SSL errors: " << errors;
        qDebug() << "peer's certificate: "
                 << reply->sslConfiguration().peerCertificate();
    }

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Handler handler;

    // CA certs for:
    // 1. cert with Subject.CN == mail.google.com cert with serial 1f:19:f6:de:35:dd:63:a1:42:91:8a:d5:2c:c0:ab:12
    // 2. cert with Subject.CN == www.google.com cert with serial 2F:DF:BC:F6:AE:91:52:6D:0F:9A:A3:DF:40:34:3E:9A
    QList<QSslCertificate> CAcerts =
            // serial 30:00:00:02
            QSslCertificate::fromPath("ThawteSGCCA.crt") +
            // serial 70:BA:E4:1D:10:D9:29:34:B6:38:CA:7B:03:CC:BA:BF
            QSslCertificate::fromPath("BuiltinObjectToken-VerisignClass3PublicPrimaryCertificationAuthority.crt");

    qDebug() << "root CA certificates:\n"
             << CAcerts
             << "\n";
    QSslSocket::setDefaultCaCertificates(CAcerts); // line A

    QWebPage page;
    // OK because cert with serial 1f:19:f6:de:35:dd:63:a1:42:91:8a:d5:2c:c0:ab:12 is for host mail.google.com
//  page.mainFrame()->load(QUrl("https://mail.google.com")); // line B1
    // SSL ERROR "The host name did not match any of the valid hosts for this certificate"
    // because cert with serial 1f:19:f6:de:35:dd:63:a1:42:91:8a:d5:2c:c0:ab:12 is NOT for www.gmail.com
    page.mainFrame()->load(QUrl("https://www.gmail.com")); // line B2

    QObject::connect(page.networkAccessManager(), SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &handler, SLOT(slotFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    QObject::connect(page.networkAccessManager(), SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)), &handler, SLOT(slotSslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)));
    QObject::connect(&page, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), &handler, SLOT(slotLoadFinished(bool)));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Ya i have used the root cerificates of the authorities who have issues the certs to gmail. and included in my root cert store . somehow  i am able to connect to https://www.google.com but https://gmail.com gives ssl errors. so will it be problem pertaining to root certificte ??

Comment: @Ashish See new version of my answer.

Comment: @Ashish Is there anything missing in my answer?

Comment: So what is the workaround of such problem (The document has moved) and how mozilla does it precisely ?

Comment: @Ashish "The document has moved" and other HTTP redirections (HTTP status codes 3xx) are handled for you by QNetworkAccessManger used by QtWebKit (QWebPage, QWebFrame). QNAM follows all these redirects and you get the contents of the final page.

Comment: Is it default with QNAM ? If yes then why QNAM is not able to get content of the redirected page ?

Comment: @Ashish Yes, it's default. I can't quess what's the reason QNAM is not able to get the page; run my code and post the output to some pastebin.

Comment: It I ignore the SSL errors then an then only It works. e.g. reply->ignoreSslErrors(); in slotSslErrors slot.