# QWebView not loading https://www.gmail.com using Qt 4.7?

Tags: qt, qwebview

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "browser.h"
#include <QtNetwork/QSslSocket>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Browser b;
    b.setGeometry(0,0,700,700);
    b.load(QUrl("https://www.gmail.com"));
    b.show();

    return a.exec();
}

class Browser : public QWebView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Browser(QWidget *parent = 0) {}

signals:

    void loadFinished ( bool ok );
    void    loadProgress ( int progress );
    void    loadStarted ();

public slots:
    void loadFinishedSlot ( bool ok );
    void    loadProgressSlot ( int progress );
    void    loadStartedSlot ();


};
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831739/

Comment: i had the problem the same to you, can you tell me how to solove it ? thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt uses OpenSSL library for https requests.

Did you install OpenSSL library ?

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/openssl.htm

Comment: I am using ubuntu 9.04 with openssl pre-installed in it and i am using qt 4.7. which take root certificates stored in /etc/ssl/certs path , so how come mozilla loads it since it is also using same openssl and certificates ?

Comment: So, did you build Qt 4.7 SDK with -openssl switch in configure step ?

Comment: If you think your problem relates to ssl validation error then see at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkreply.html#ignoreSslErrors

Comment: Some words about Mozilla ... As I remember Mozilla has its own certificate storage independently from your system. So Mozilla can establish trust relationship with more wide area of issued certificates than your system.

Comment: Also you can use **QNetworkRequest::setSslConfiguration** for every network request. There you can specify your own **QSslConfiguration**. This is more secure approach. For more information see: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qnetworkrequest.html#setSslConfiguration

Comment: i have used QSslSocket::setDefaultCaCertificates() to override the certificates which mozilla uses.